# Cannot able to input String after Int in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am inputing k and choice (Integers) in Main class. And then trying to input title_name in count class. But ,I am not able to input title_name.

//Main class

```
    package com.iiitd.ap.lab6;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static int k;
    static int option;



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        k=in.nextInt();
        option=in.nextInt();
        in.close();

        System.out.println(k+" "+option);

        count t=new count(k,option);
        t.count_print();


    }

}
```

//count class

```
package com.iiitd.ap.lab6;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class count {
    static int k;
    static int option;

    count(int k, int option)
    {
        count.k= k;
        count.option= option;

    }



    int  decide_file_1() throws IOException
    {

        String title_name="";
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        title_name=in.next();
        System.out.println("ttt");
            in.close();

        for(int i=1;i<=20;++i){
        FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("/home/tarun/Downloads/Lab6/Papers/paper"+i+".txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
        System.out.println(title_name+" "+br.readLine());
            if(title_name.equals(br.readLine()))
                return i;               

        }

        return 0;

    }





    int count_print() throws IOException
    {
        if(option==1)
        {   
            System.out.printf("decide_file=%d",decide_file_1());

        }
        return 0;

    }




}
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It it related somewhere to concurrent access of input stream/resource? anyone having the exact explanation?

Comment: What do you mean "But ,I am not able to input title_name." ?are you getting any error ?

Comment: You have closed the input stream in your main... Don't do that..

Comment: @Codebender, he instantiates a new Scanner in the `count` class, so it's not that...

Comment: @Tgsmith61591, instantiating a new Scanner wont help... The underlying stream is already closed... You cannot reopen a closed stream...

Comment: @Codebender It worked, after removing in.close(). But can You explain why this is behaving like this?

Comment: @tarun14110, I have given an explanation as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the Standard input stream (`System.in`) by calling `in.close()`.

From the [Scanner#close() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()),

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then **if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked.** If this scanner is already closed then invoking this method will have no effect.

This means that it will invoke the **input stream's** close() method, there by closing the stream and disconnecting the connection between your read console and the java program.

So, you cannot use `System.in` stream anymore in the program (doesn't matter if you are using a new Scanner() object or not).

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the line twice:

```
System.out.println(title_name+" "+br.readLine());
        if(title_name.equals(br.readLine()))
            return i;
```

Store the value before printing and comparing. Once you read the line, the reader advances. So, the second readLine() call is getting the next line in the stream.

```
String title = br.readLine();
System.out.println(title_name+" "+title);
            if(title_name.equals(title))
                return i;
```

Comment: Actually I have written the System.out.println() line , just to check is there something in title_name or not. But it is empty.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I might also suggest placing your Scanner inside a try-with-resources block which makes it easier to view the scope of your stream.